# Radio button group common to two columns of a datagrid in flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, itemrenderer, radio-group

In my application i am having a datagrid in which for 2 columns i need to set radio button as itemrenderer.But the thing is if we select one radio button,the next one have to get deselected.So i thought of achieving this by using one common radio group for both radio buttons but its not working(Both the radio buttons are selectable).But i need one radio button to get selected one time.
Any suggestions...
My code as follows

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Buy Offer" dataField="buyoffer">
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:RadioButton id="chk1"   groupName="{components.BuyRadioGroup}" horizontalCenter="0"/>
        </mx:HBox>
    </fx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Get Offer" dataField="getoffer">
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <fx:Component>
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:RadioButton id="chk2" groupName="{components.BuyRadioGroup}" horizontalCenter="0"/>
        </mx:HBox>
    </fx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```

Comment: Based on the code you show, I do not understand how you are 'sharing' a radio button group.  You said it is not working, but didn't tell us how it is working and why that is different than what you desire.  Such information is very helpful to us.   Generically, make the selected value of the radio button contigent on a property value on the data object the renderer is displaying.

Comment: Hi @Reboog711 i edited my question.What i want is, if one radio button got selected the next one should get automatically deselected.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a common or shared Radio Button Group is the appropriate solution.

Having a single RBG passed to each renderer will result in behavior where by changing a selection for one item (i.e. row in the grid) will affect the other rows.

Instead, as Reboog711 suggested, consider binding the selected value of each Radio Button to an appropriate value of your domain object.

I would suggest a reusable renderer which can represent the possible values for the `type` of Offer. This will reduce much of your code duplication and make changes quite simple.

```
<mx:DataGrid dataProvider="{offerList}">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Buy Offer">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <local:OfferTypeIR offerType="{OfferType.BUY}"/>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Get Offer">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <local:OfferTypeIR offerType="{OfferType.GET}"/>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Add the relevant property to your domain object:

```
public class Offer
{
    [Bindable]
    public var type : OfferType = OfferType.BUY;
}
```

And in your renderer:

```
<mx:HBox>

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            [Bindable]
            public var offerType : OfferType;

            [Bindable("dataChange")]
            public function get offer() : Offer
            {
                return data as Offer;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:RadioButton selected="{offer.type == offerType}"
                    change="offer.type = offerType"/>

</mx:HBox>
```